# Book request: mathematical logic with a semantical emphasis.

Tags: logic, reference-request, book-recommendation

Suppose I am interested in the semantical aspect of logic; especially the satisfaction $\models$ relation between models and sentences, and the induced semantic consequence relation $\implies,$ defined by asserting that $\Gamma \implies \varphi$ iff whenever $M \models \Gamma$ we have $M \models \varphi$. Suppose, however, that I am **not** currently interested in any of the following (admittedly very important) issues.

1. Founding mathematics.
2. Formal systems, and the limitations of formal systems.
3. Recursive axiomatizability.
4. Computability theory.

Given my particular mathematical interests, can anyone recommend a good, fairly elementary mathematical logic book?

Comment: I think that is difficult to read an "elementary mathematical logic (text)book" skipping the chapters regarding Formal systems (i.e.syntax) and Computability theory. Regarding model theory textbooks (like **J.L.Bell & A.B.Slomson**, *Models and Ultraproducts* (1969 - also Dover reprint) and **C.C.Chang, H.Jerome Keisler**, Model Theory (2nd ed 1977 - also Dover reprint), I think they are more difficult. I thinh you can try with **H.Enderton**, *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic* (2nd ed - 2001), that is more oriented towards the interplay between language and structures than proof systems.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, thanks for the references. However, I'm not sure syntax should be viewed as synonymous with formal systems, since many theories are not recursively enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find an annotated guide to model theory (in fact two guides, an initial pass through elementary books, and then a more advanced guide) in the general reading Guide to logic text books you can download here:

http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/TeachYourselfLogic9-4.pdf

That should give you enough information to be able to send you to the right books in the library given your particular interests.

Given the way the question is phrased, you might possibly also be interested in this side note:

http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/Galois.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for or exactly what your background is, but the first time I saw model theory was with [*Model Theory: an Introduction*](http://books.google.com/books?id=QieAHk--GCcC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) by David Marker. I think it might be something you are interested in.

Comment: I'm working through this book right now. Minus one small collision with the fact that he never defines satisfaction for a collection of formulas (which is annoying if you're reading about omitting types for the first time) it's a rather nice introduction and a fair bit gentler than, say, Chang & Keisler.

Answer (score 1):

The book "Éléments de Logique Mathématique" by Kreisel and Krivine (which I believe has an English translation, probably with the obvious title "Elements of Mathematical Logic") takes a fiercely semantical approach to the basic parts of mathematical logic.  The material you don't want, about the axiomatic method and foundations of mathematics, is relegated to a couple of appendices.

Comment: It's right : Georg Kreisel & Jean Louis Krivine, *Elements of Mathematical Logic (Model Theory)* (North Holland, 1967).

Comment: Thanks: this "fiercely semantical" book does not disappoint.